# rename/delete a folder from multipart rar file

Tags: archiving, rar, winrar

I've a question: (I sent it in past)
I have multipart rar file.
Their contents are:

file.part01.rar:

> myfolder (is a folder)
>
> > data.cab -->

file.part02.rar:

> myfolder (is a folder)
>
> > data.cab <->

file.part03.rar:

> myfolder (is a folder)
>
> > data.cab <->

file.part04.rar:

> difffolder (is a folder)
>
> > anfolder (is a folder)
> >
> > > data.cab <->

file.part05.rar:

> myfolder (is a folder)
>
> > data.cab <--

I want to extract it, so I right-click on "file.part01.rar" and select "Extract to ...".
It extract 3 files, but in part 4, WinRAR said: "CRC. This file is currput."

I think it problem is in the folders name in part04.rar.
Is there anyway to rename folders in part04.rar? and cut "data.cab" from "afolder" to "difffolder".
I really need it!! it is very emergency!!!!!!!!

Thank you .....

Answer (score 1):

No, if one part of a multi-part RAR archive is corrupt then you are essentially missing some data from that part, in which case the original image is virtually impossible to rebuild.

Multi-part RAR archives do not just send some files to one piece of the archive and some files to another piece of the archive, there is no telling what you are missing in the part of the archive that is corrupt.  It could be just one file, or it could be a small piece of a dozen different files.

I think you are hosed :(